# Multi language wordpress site - how to fit it with wp_bootstrap_navwalker and bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set multi language menu for a worpdress website with bootstrap and wp_bootstrap_navwalker. I've managed to make one menu with one language work. But when I try to add another menu/language the website it, just dissapears. Can anybody help?

My functions.php file code is:

```
if (function_exists ('add_theme_support')) {

add_theme_support ('menus');
```

}

//Create Nav Menu
if (function_exists ('register_nav_menu')) {
        register_nav_menus (array(

```
                        'esp' => 'Spanish menu',
                        'eng' => 'English menu',
                        'fra' => 'French menu',
                        'deu' => 'Deutsch menu'

    ));
```

}

and my header.php code is:

```
<?php 

                    if ($language == 'en' || $lan == 'en') {

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'eng',
                                        'container_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
                                        'container' => 'nav'
                        ));

                    } else if ($language == 'fr' || $lan == 'fr') {

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'fra',
                                        'container_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
                                        'container' => 'nav'
                        ));

                    } else if ($language == 'de' || $lan == 'de') {

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'deu',
                                        'container_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
                                        'container' => 'nav'
                        ));

                    } else {

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'esp',
                                        'depth' => 2,
                                        'container' => false,
                                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                        );

                    }

                ?>
```

So when I change to this:

```
<?php 

                    if ($language == 'en' || $lan == 'en') {

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'eng',
                                        'depth' => 2,
                                        'container' => false,
                                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                        ));

                    } else if ($language == 'fr' || $lan == 'fr') {

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'fra',
                                        'container_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
                                        'container' => 'nav'
                        ));

                    } else if ($language == 'de' || $lan == 'de') {

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'deu',
                                        'container_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
                                        'container' => 'nav'
                        ));

                    } else {

                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'esp',
                                        'depth' => 2,
                                        'container' => false,
                                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                        );

                    }

                ?>
```

The whole site dissapears.